# $\pi_1 $ of space of positive-definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, positive-definite

I am trying to find the fundamental group of the space of positive-definite matrices that are also symmetric with entries that are real. Call this space $M$.

Where to begin? From particular examples, I think that this group is the identity group $[e]$, but this is only intuition.
What do loops in in $M$ look like?  I have an idea of what a path looks like.

Example:
for $$\lambda \in [0,1]$$ we  get  $$x^T(\lambda A+(1-\lambda)B)x > 0$$
with $A$ and $B$ inside M and $x$ a vector, so $f(\lambda)=\lambda A+(1-\lambda)B$ is a path in $M$.

Will I need to consider van Kampen's theorems or is there a more direct way? Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $M$ is convex, it is contractible and so its fundamental group is trivial.  Explicitly, fix some $A\in M$ and define $f:M\times[0,1]\to M$ by $f(B,\lambda)=\lambda A+(1-\lambda)B$, and then $f$ is a contraction of $M$.

Comment: That's right, the fact that the straight line path stays in $M$ is what makes it convex and thus contractible.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you